# How can I remotely edit/create a wiki for a GitHub Repo?

Tags: c#, java, git, github

I am writing an application in c# that presents a form for developers to fill out. The application takes in information about the repositories (repos) and then puts it into a wiki template. Once I format and save to an .md file, I would like to push it to the repository. I just got done converting a few hundred repositories from SVN to an enterprise version GitHub and none of them have wikis. I want to give the developers an easy way to outline what the code is and where it came from without them having to format etc. I already know about 'gitaccess' and the Ruby api. These, however, require a full clone of the repo before a wiki can be pushed to it. I do not want this. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer, but it's still relevant.  You can use a batch file to script the push commands, and then use gitcredentials, which is built into git, to handle the username and password prompts, which should allow you to script the entire process of pushing the wiki pages.  See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcredentials.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks that's on the right track. I am planning on executing batch from the program but I really need to avoid having them download 200 repos into their computers just to document them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wiki link from the top action bar from within the repo. Within the Wiki area, you can create pages desired right from the web by clicking the New Page button. There are also Edit and Preview buttons on the web page for viewing before you save the Wiki document.

To add to this, I did not realize you were trying to script your changes. The wiki exists in a separate, but parallel repo to the code repo and you do not have to clone the code repo to get the wiki repo (although you do need to clone the wiki repo). You can access the xyz.git repo's wiki using xyz.wiki.git. On the Wiki page (which you already know about), and of course, you can get the URL by clicking on the Git Access button at the top.

If you really can't clone the wiki repos, Git offers only a total of 4 protocols as specified in the [Git Documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html). Here is a blog post that talks about [8 ways to share your git repository](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/), which may give you some clues to other ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: I am aware of how to manually create a wiki within the GitHub interface. I would like to do it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023-03, creating wiki (git) repositories on GitHub programmatically is not officially supported.

GitHub's official REST API (Version: 2022-11-28) supports the [creation of repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user). However, if you try to create a "wiki" for some code repository, named say "REPOSITORY_NAME" (meaning, you want to create the git repository "REPOSITORY_NAME.wiki"), will end up with an error like:

```
{
  "message": "Repository creation failed.",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Repository",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "name",
      "message": "name cannot end in .wiki"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
gh: Repository creation failed. (HTTP 422)
```

AFAIK then, your only chance is to create the wiki repository using the non-documented call from the GitHub website:

- On your browser, if you want to create a wiki manually, you will see that this is a call to a `GET` method with the URL pattern: `https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/wiki/_new`. This redirects you to a new site with the title "Create new page".
- Inspecting the button `Save page` (id: `gollum-editor-submit`) shows you that the underlying routine to create a wiki git repository is a POST method with the pattern `https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/wiki` (the web HTML includes a hidden `input` with the name `authenticity_token`; again this is not documented and is likely to change). Calling this method with the right inputs (and I guess some needed headers) will create your desired new git repository.
- Finally, to later push your git repository from scratch, you will need to force it: `git push -f origin`.